# Full customisation of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm currently building an iOS Application for a client and have hit a pretty huge roadblock. I mean, I could write my own UINavigationBar and such but that would cause a lot of issues further down the road.

I have tried everything in my knowledge so far and have spent several hours searching for a solution (overriding the CALayer, using CoreGraphics and pretty much everything else ) and I get the same result. No matter how hard I try to remove the background of the UINavigationBar, it still shows a white background with slight translucency.

I need to have a lot of customisation on the navigation bar (I.E having a gradient going from "blackColor" to "clearColor" and I can't do that if the background of the Navigation Bar refuses to be **completely** transparent. I have tried copying all of the CALayers from the UINavigationBar layer to a subview I added and it just kept crashing, even when replacing the delegates and superlayer.

I really need help with this. One of the multiple effects I'm trying to achieve are below. (The blue rectangle is not the focus of the image, it's irrelevant.)

[image: App image]

Comment: I don't understand why using a custom UINavigationBar is a problem...

Comment: I've overridden the UINavigationBar and there is no way (I know) to make it work. When I'm using a UINavigationController, it's really complicated if I don't use a UINavigationBar subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it completely transparent:

```
(UINavigationBar.appearance()).translucent = true
(UINavigationBar.appearance()).barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
(UINavigationBar.appearance()).backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
(UINavigationBar.appearance()).setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
(UINavigationBar.appearance()).shadowImage = UIImage()
```

EDIT:
Using iOS 8.3 looking like this:

[image]

Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's not completely transparent, that's a solid color with slight transparency.

Comment: Transparent over here :) Am I missing something maybe? What iOS version are we talking about?

Comment: I was testing on iOS 7 :(

Comment: I have just tested on iOS 8 and I get the same result as what I was getting before... I'm not using Storyboard if that makes a difference?

Comment: I've managed to replicate what you have done on a different project I made. This is the correct answer, sorry. It's my bad haha.

Comment: Interesting thing is.. it works if there is anything behind it with exception to a UIScrollView with content haha

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the top Navbar with the back button and Save button right? I'm just confused as to what the blue box on the image is in reference too.

Anyways, this is an extremely hacky approach but could work:

Set the `UINavigationBar`'s `alpha` to 0.  The Back button and Save button will probably also disappear but you could just add labels to the View Controller at the top in the exact same place.  The button's should still be functional even though they are "invisible" but the user will still think they are touching them.

Again, very hacky, but you are free to play with the top part of the View then.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I'm not near a computer with XCode at the moment and can't test it out, and this fix may not even work but I thought I'd offer up a possible temporary solution.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want a really hacky solution, that's the problem. I wish there could be a simple, non-hacky solution.

Comment: @JoeyClover Stack Exchange is a network of question & answer sites, not the Make-a-Wish foundation.  I don't know if there is a clean, simple solution to what you're asking (your question isn't super clear on what you've tried, what results you got, etc), but this may be the best solution... maybe not...

Comment: Yeah, I hear that.  Sorry but you may have to subclass and customize both the UINavigationController and UINavigationBar.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @nhgrif for the extremely obvious statement. I asked a question expecting to receive an answer. I'm awaiting more answers to see if anyone has a more creative, less hacky solution, that's all. Cheers PD1ce

Comment: Whoa whoa, mine may be hacky but I think it's pretty creative.  Just messing, but I think you could do something along the lines of what I've suggested, just make it so that your custom view controller automatically adds those labels.  Another solution may be to just set up a different type of view controller and set up the navigation constraints yourself, that way everything is custom and you can do what you wish.  Tbh, I often set up navigation and transitions using a basic ViewController, that way I have full control for what I'm designing.